# Audio Player: Load random song from database table without repeating

Tags: php, mysql, database, audio, html5-audio

I've got a problem with my audio player (http://www.vegapohl.com/audio). I'm trying to have the player play a random track from a mysql database, but I don't want it to play a previous song. Only once all songs have been listened to or skipped, it should "reset" and play all tracks again.

Here is my PHP:

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "db57276_11", "*****")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db(db57276_11)or die("cannot select DB");


$sql = "SELECT * FROM audio ORDER BY RAND()";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if (false === $result) {
    echo mysql_error();
}
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
$url = $row[0];
$title = $row[1];
$artist = $row[2];
$albumart = $row[3];
?>
```

I found some answers to similar questions on stackoverflow, but none of them worked for me. To give you a better idea of the general functionality, here is the body markup:

```
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function playPause(soundId,getImg) {
setTimeout(swapImg,30000,getImg);
soundId.volume=.5;
 if (soundId.paused){
     soundId.play();       
 getImg.src='pause.png';


}
   else {
       soundId.pause();
        getImg.src='play.png';
   }

}

function swapImg(getImg){
getImg.src='play.png';
}
</script>
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="wrapmiddle">
    <div class="middle">

        <div class="track">
            <h1><?php echo $title; ?></h1>
            <h2><?php echo $artist; ?></h2>
            <div id="buttons">
<a href="javascript:window.location.reload()" class="next">Skip</a>
<a href="#"class="like">Share</a><a href="#" class="view">Visit Site</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="left">
<div>
    <audio id="track1" onended = "window.location.reload()">
    <source src="<?php echo $url; ?>" type="audio/mp3"></source>
    Your browser does not support this content.</audio>
    <a href="#" onClick="playPause(track1,playImg1);">
<img alt="" class="playImg"    src="play.png" style="cursor: pointer;" name="playImg1" />   
</a><br />
</div>
</div>
  <div class="right">
  <div class="overlay"><img src="icon.png" width="35" height="34" /> </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Maybe someone knows of a better way of playing the next track (instead of refreshing the page/iframe). If it could play each track in the table in order and then start from the top again that would also work. Hope someone can help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an additional smallint field to your SQL table, something like `status`. In that store a 1 or 0 (or something else you devise) to mean unplayed/unskipped, or played/skipped. In your SQL query, add a where clause along the lines of `SELECT songname,artist,filelocation,status FROM audio WHERE status=0 ORDER BY rand()`

Comment: Hey, thanks, but what if multiple people are using the player? I want to keep it local.

Comment: Sorry, I did not see anything related to multiple users being a requirement in your original question. To answer properly though, it really depends on how your users data is linked to your audio data. Post that information and a more formulated answer can be made.

Comment: There is no link between user data and audio data. I don't have a user base. This audio player would be embedded on other websites in an iframe and people can listen to or skip tracks. More or less like this: https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/spotify-play-button/ Just that it would be able to play multiple songs instead of one.

Comment: Ahh, I see. I would suggest then the method proposed by @moonwave99. Create a random playlist array and store it in a cookie or a session variable. Check that for the next song to play, or create if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Is it possible to do this using ajax so the page doesn't have to refreshed?

Comment: @MatteoCuellarVega More than likely; give it a try! Although that question and implementation falls outside the scope of this question.

Answer (score 0):

Fetch a random playlist on the first request, and use it throughout the visit.

If you want such playlist to persist between page reloads, store it in your `$_SESSION`.

Comment: Hey, sounds like that would work, if possible could you expand a bit on that. Not super familiar with php. Thank you.